# cross fade background image on click

Tags: javascript, css

the java script code in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/cwP5Q/) is auto slide images, but i need to convert this as onclick code,when i click .box1 classes.

and when i click box1 classes crosssfade only have to be effect to background image which is in id=#main. cross fade must not effect to box1 and it has to be continuously appeared when background image cross fade.

for crossfade the background image, images have to connect with directly to the image 
folder. for that i need to connect with image folder and background image in #main.

can some body help with this.

[my code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/8uGKH/)

```
var timer = setInterval(nextImage, 4000);
var curImage = 0;
var numImages = 5;

function nextImage() {
    var e;
    // remove showMe class from current image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    removeClass(e, "showMe");
    // compute next image
    curImage++;
    if (curImage > numImages - 1) {
        curImage = 0;
    }

    // add showMe class to next image
    e = document.getElementById("slideimg" + curImage);
    addClass(e, "showMe");
}

function addClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    if (c) c += " ";  // if not blank, add a space separator
    c += name;
    elem.className = c;
}

function removeClass(elem, name) {
    var c = elem.className;
    elem.className = c.replace(name, "").replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");  // remove name and extra blanks
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following JSfiddle to change image on clcik

http://jsfiddle.net/arunberti/cwP5Q/99/

Write the function inside the below code

```
$('#container').click(function() {

});
```